# NelmioSecurityBundle forced_ssl OFF in dev, ON in prod, possible?

Tags: symfony, https

Is there any way to set the `nelmio_security.forced_ssl.enabled` setting to `true` on prod and `false` on dev? I don't have an ssl certificate for my local dev machine. Maybe some way to make a `dist.yml` for the security where only the `nelmio_security` needs to be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameters.

config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters_prod.yml }
nelmio_security:
    forced_ssl:
        enabled: %ssl_enabled%
```

config_dev.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters_dev.yml }
nelmio_security:
    forced_ssl:
        enabled: %ssl_enabled%
```

parameters_dev.yml:

```
parameters:
    ssl_enabled: false
```

parameters_prod.yml (or parameters.yml):

```
parameters:
    ssl_enabled: true
```

and make sure you AppKernel call the right config file...

Comment: thanks! such an obvious answer in the end :) I ended up just putting `ssl_enabled: true` in my `parameters.dist.yml` and then setting it to false on dev, fewer files to manage this way.

Comment: @VBee no need for parameters. define enabled to false in the config.yml and feel happy ^^